# Gradle running Spock integration test from a different module

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, spock

I have my integration-test in a different module, however I have single gradle.build file.

When I'm running `gradle clean integrationTest` I get the following error

`Task :integrationTest NO-SOURCE
Skipping task ':integrationTest' as it has no source files and no previous output files.`

In the logs I see the following:

`file or directory '<MyPath>/MyService/src/integrationTest/groovy'', not found`

However the path should be `<MyPath>/MyService/integrationTest/src/test/groovy`

my gradle.build file have the following:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'integration-test/src/test/groovy'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'integration-test/src/test/resources'
        }
    }
 }

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the integration tests as a separate 'module', but not as a Gradle project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `srcDir(<path>)` *appends* another source path. So Gradle will still search in *src/integrationTest/groovy*, which is the conventional path.

If you want to replace the convention, use

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = [file('integration-test/src/test/groovy')] as Set
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = [file('integration-test/src/test/resources')] as Set
        }
    }
}
```

However, there's no need to remove the conventional path. I wonder whether your path is correct, because you say in your post that the path should include 'integrationTest', but you're specifying 'integration-test' in the example code.